# Laravel PATCH/DELET Request - MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: php, laravel, request, laravel-5.5

I'm playing around with PATCH / DELETE Request but are not able to proceed the required requests.

**Error**: MethodNotAllowedHttpException

When I switch completely to POST-Requests,I'm receiving a page is not longer active error.

**Route-File**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '/users', 'namespace' => 'Users', 'as' => 'administrators.users.'], function () {

    Route::get('/', 'UsersController@index')->name('index');

    Route::get('/create', 'UsersController@create')->name('create');
    Route::post('/create', 'UsersController@store')->name('store');

    Route::get('/edit/{user}', 'UsersController@edit')->name('edit');
    Route::patch('/update/{user}', 'UsersController@update')->name('update');

    Route::patch('/activate/{user}', 'UsersController@activate')->name('activate');
    Route::patch('/deactivate/{user}', 'UsersController@deactivate')->name('deactivate');

    Route::delete('/delete/{user}', 'UsersController@delete')->name('delete');
});
```

**View-Form-Request**

```
<a href="#" onclick="event.preventDefault();document.getElementById('activate-form').submit();" class="badge badge-success">Activate</a>

<form id="activate-form" action="{{ route('administrators.users.activate', $user) }}" method="POST"
style="display: none;">
{{ csrf_field() }}
{{ method_field('PATCH') }}
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
 public function activate(User $user)
    {
        if(!auth()->user()->isSameAs($user))
        {
            $user->active = true;
            $user->save();
        }

        return back();
    }
```

Comment: Looking at your Javascript you're submitting a form named `deactivate-form` but the form with your `method_field` is called `activate-form` — you're probably submitting the wrong form, a form that doesn't contain `method_field`. If that doesn't help then the next step is to check your browsers network request tab and see if the `_method` parameter is being sent with your `POST` request as that is how Laravel knows if it's a `PATCH` request.

Comment: Hey sam, thank for your answer. Your right,  but, I just copied one form, i've a couple of form with activate, deactivate and so on. I adjusted the question above. I've to check the network request with, one second.

Comment: In your route file, you reference the namespace as administrator.user but the form route is points at administrators.user (plural). See if fixing that typo helps

Comment: Hey Rob thanks for your answer, I manually entered the administrator(s) and made a typo. There is outside the file another route group with the correct syntax. I updated the question above.

Comment: You said there is another route group? I have found that duplicated route locations can cause the MethodNotAllowedHttpException error, especially if they lead to the same endpoint. Check that....